# Remove elements from a column of tuples in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe that have as its value either a string or a tuple containing multiple strings, like the one bellow:

```
           Country                                              Roles  \
0  Shell Record  (DSC Payroll Administrator Reporting, DSC HR S...   
1            PL  (DSC Payroll Administrator Reporting, DSC Payr...   
2            ES  (DSC HR Business Partner Reporting, DSC HR Bus...   
3  Shell Record  (DSC HR Business Partner Reporting, DSC HR Bus...   
4  Shell Record                     DSC BPM Worklist Administrator   

          Role vs Family  
0           Do not match  
1  (Match, Do not match)  
2                  Match  
3           Do not match  
4           Do not match
```

Is there a way I can remove the values inside the tuple (for example, remove the Match/Do not match so the value in the column would just be the same without the parenthesis). I don't want to use "replace" for that (or even don't know if it is possible).

Thank you!

Comment: It can be done like it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894525/how-to-remove-parentheses-and-all-data-within-using-pandas-python), however, they do use a regex `replace`

Comment: Does not work, it actually return NaN value instead of removing just the parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['(Match, Do not match)', 'Match', 'Do not match']})
print(df)
```

Before:

```
                     col
0  (Match, Do not match)
1                  Match
2           Do not match
```

This regex expression should remove all parenthesis from the column.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[(|)]', '', x))
print(df)
```

After:

```
                   col
0  Match, Do not match
1                Match
2         Do not match
```