# how can I remove a parentheses "( )" from an Index with Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

### I have an output like this:

```
Vanuatu                                22        10
Venezuela(Bolivarian Republic of)      32        10
Viet Nam                               44        05
```

### and I want something like this:

```
Vanuatu                                22        10
Venezuela                              32        10
Viet Nam                               44        05
```

Imagine that I have a Data Frame too long, like 500 Indexes.
How can I do to remove it from all in my DF?

Comment: See [How to remove parentheses and all data within using Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56701635/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is exactly what you are looking for:

```
import re
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Vanuatu', 'Venezuela(Bolivarian Republic of)','Viet Nam' ]})
```

Use regex expression to call and replace anything between the parenthesis and the parenthesis themselves

```
df['Name']=df.Name.str.replace('\(+[A-Za-z|\s+\)]+','')
df
```

Explanation
`\(` -special character `(`

`+` match anything to the left

`A-Za-z` match any upper or lower case letters

`|` or

`\s` white space

`+` match anything to the left

`\)` special character `)`

combined `[A-Za-z|\s+\)]`+ match any upper and lower cases or white spaces to the left

[image]