# Pandas removing parts from string

Tags: python, pandas, string

I've got a Dataframe containing strings like this

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |
| [First] nenen | row |
| [Second] mmm | row |

I want to remove all the text in brackets ([xxx]) and keep the rest of the string in each row.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove parentheses and all data within using Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894525/how-to-remove-parentheses-and-all-data-within-using-pandas-python)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56701635/3279716) for a look at the difference between the regex in the answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df
         a header another header
0           first            row
1  [First] second            row
>>> df["a header"]=df["a header"].str.replace(r'\[.*?\]\ *','')
>>> df
  a header another header
0    first            row
1   second            row
```