# Cutting a string in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have values in my query that looks like the following:
`Decrease with an active address (2)` or `Unsecured task (100)` etc.

The value within the parentheses varies, it can be one, two, three digits or more because this is a count value.

I just need to get the description not the parentheses nor the value.
So what I need is just:

```
Decrease with an active address
Unsecured task
```

etc.

How can I get rid of the opening `(`, the numeric value and the closing `)`?

In ColdFusion 8?

Comment: With `reReplace()`.  Or, if the stuff you want is always at the end, a combination of `left()` and `find()` will work.

Answer (score 2):

As Dan mentioned in the comments, one option is using [reReplace()](http://cfdocs.org/rereplace) with the appropriate expression to [remove any text within parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex):

```
<cfscript>
    origText = "Decrease with an active address (2)";
    newText = reReplaceNoCase(origText, "\([^)]*\)", "", "all");
    writeDump( newText );
</cfscript>
```

**Update:**

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769733/alex) mentioned in the comments, if you just want to "cut" the string, and grab the part *before* the parenthesis, try something like this:

```
<cfscript>
    origText = "Decrease with an active address (2) plus more text after the parenthesis";
    newText = reReplaceNoCase(origText, "\([0-9]*\).*$", "", "all");
    writeOutput("<br>"& newText );
</cfscript>
```

Comment: And if you only want to remove trailing parenthesis with numbers (as described in the question), use `\([0-9]*\)$` as the second parameter in the `reReplaceNoCase`.

Comment: @Alex - That is a good point. I read it as "remove it", but looking over the title, your suggestion is probably closer to the mark.