# How to find characters not in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

Attempting to find all occurrences of characters

```
string1 = '%(example_1).40s-%(example-2)_-%(example3)s_'
```

so that output has all occurrences of '-' '_' not in parentheses

```
['-', '_', '-', '_']
```

Do not need to care about nested parentheses

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex

Comment: Can you give an example of the input-output ?

Comment: `str` is a builtin try not to use that as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you your output.:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = '%(example_1).40s-%(example-2)_-%(example3)s_'
>>> print list("".join(re.findall("[-_]+(?![^(]*\))", str)))
['-', '_', '-', '_']
```

What this does is it finds all the substrings containing `'-'` and/or `'_'` in `str` and not in parentheses. Since these are substrings, we get all such matching characters by joining, and splitting into a list.

Comment: Awesome.  Can you explain what `[^(]*\))` is doing?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. @pylang [^(]*\)) matches all characters within the parantheses.

Answer (score 5):

You can use module `re` to do that by passing regex to it

```
import re

str = '%(example_1).40s-%(example-2)_-%(example3)s_'
#remove all occurences of paratheses and what is inside
tmpStr = re.sub('\(([^\)]+)\)', '', str)

#take out other element except your caracters
tmpStr = re.sub('[^_-]', '', tmpStr)

#and transform it to list
result_list = list(tmpStr)
```

Result

```
['-', '_', '-', '_']
```

And like Bharath shetty has mentioned it in comment, do not use `str`, it's a reserved word in python for built-in strings