# Remove certain word using regular expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I have a string which is shown below:

```
a = 'steven (0.00030s ). prince (0.00040s ). kavin (0.000330s ). 23.24.21'
```

I want to remove the numbers inside `()` and the brackets and want to have it like this:

```
a = 'steven  prince  kavin  23.24.21'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html you can certainly find the answer there :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove text within parentheses with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re
a = 'steven (0.00030s ). prince (0.00040s ). kavin (0.000330s ). 23.24.21'
print(re.sub(r"(\(.*?\)\.)", "", a))
```

**Output:**

```
steven  prince  kavin  23.24.21
```

Comment: Why the outer group?  Why `.*?` rather than `.+`?

Comment: Personally I would go for a much more restrictive RE:  `\([0-9]+\.[0-9]s \)\.`

Comment: Ah, yes.  But `.*` will match "nothing inside the brackets" too  (I was confusing `.*?` with `.*.?` which is equivalent to `.+`)