# How can I remove texts within parentheses with a regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I refer [the stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex)

but it is not working.

how I solve my problem?

```
def clean_text(text):
    pattern = '([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)' 
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
    pattern = '(http|ftp|https)://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
    pattern = '([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ]+)'  
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
    pattern = '<[^>]*>'        
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
    pattern = '[^\w\s]'        
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
    pattern = '\([^)]*\)'  ## not working!!
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
    return text   

text = '(abc_def) 좋은글! (이것도 지워조) http://1234.com 감사합니다. aaa@goggle.comㅋㅋ<H1>thank you</H1>'
clean_text(text)
```

The result is **abc_def 좋은글 이것도 지워조  감사합니다 thank you**

My goal is **좋은글 감사합니다 thank you**

Comment: Your question and the expected value doesn't really match? How do you want `text` to be cleaned up? Please update your "goal"

Comment: Swap the last two re.subs. First, use `text = re.sub(pattern=r'\([^)]*\)', repl='', string=text)` and then the `'[^\w\s]'` regex replacement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are so genius!!!

Comment: I posted an answer below, it takes time on a mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `[^\w\s]` re.sub removes the parentheses and thus the last regex does not match. You may swap the last two re.subs and use

```
import re
def clean_text(text):
    pattern = '([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)' 
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text) 
    pattern = r'(?:http|ftp|https)://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+' 
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text) 
    pattern = r'[ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ]+' 
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text) 
    pattern = r'<[^>]*>' 
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)  
    pattern = r'\s*\([^)]*\)' 
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
    pattern = r'[^\w\s]' 
    text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
    return text.strip()

text = '(abc_def) 좋은글! (이것도 지워조) http://1234.com 감사합니다. aaa@goggle.comㅋㅋ<H1>thank you</H1>' 
print(clean_text(text))
```

See the [online Python demo](http://ideone.com/yDmbpl).

I suggest using raw string literals (note the `r''` prefixes) and stripping the unnecessary spaces with `text.strip()`. The `\s*` in `r'\s*\([^)]*\)'` will remove 0 or more whitespaces before parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    def clean_text(text):
        pattern = '([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)'
        text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
        pattern = '(http|ftp|https)://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+'
        text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
        pattern = '([ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ]+)'
        text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
        pattern = '<[^>]*>'
        text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
        pattern = '\([^)]*\)\s'  ## not working!!
        text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
        pattern = '[^\w\s+]'
        text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl='', string=text)
        pattern = '\s{2,}'
        text = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl=' ', string=text)
        return text
```

The result will be exact 좋은글 감사합니다 thank you