# Regex return all text other than text in MULTIPLE sets of parentheses

Tags: regex

I am looking for regex that will allow me to extract the names and drop everything inside the parentheses. Example data below.

Text string:

```
John (Juan, Jonathan, Jon, Jonny) James Doe (born on January 1, 1900)
```

Desired output:

```
John James Doe
```

Further in some cases the text string may be like:

```
John (Juan, Jonathan, Jon, Jonny) James Doe (born on January 1, 1900) (Canada)
```

and in this case we would still want returned:

```
John James Doe
```

I tried the solution from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex), but I still get the wrong output:

```
John James Doe (born on January 1, 1900)
```

Comment: Running the solution from the thread you linked works for multiple parentheses when I test. Maybe you need to clarify why that doesn't work?

Comment: It is not returning what he asked for. It is only selected the word between the parenteses. The answer he linked is not suitable. That's why he post it.

Comment: @jarcobi889 when I run the solution from the linked thread, the string I get returned is `John James Doe (born on January 1, 1900)`

Comment: Are you running this? `text = "John (Juan, Jonathan, Jon, Jonny) James Doe (born on January 1, 1900) (Canada)"` `re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', text)` `'John  James Doe  '` ? That's the output I get using the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex only and not any replace function :

`[^\S]*(\w*)(?:\s*)(?:\([^()]*\))*`

https://regex101.com/r/zF2cMM/4

**Edit :**

`(?:[^\S]*(\w*)(?:\s*)(?:\s*\([^()]*\)\S*)*)`

I have made this last one version correcting a problem on last match

You can compare V4 and V6 and see that the result is a little bit different

https://regex101.com/r/zF2cMM/6

Now this work fine.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the extra space between John and James in the returned string?

Comment: No, now the result is `JohnJamesDoe`.  And before it was `John  James Doe` (two spaces between John and James).  I need the result to be `John James Doe`.

Comment: Hmm i see now no extra space