# How to make discord bot ignore IDs?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So right now I have a bot that does the following code.

```
if '69' in message.content:
    await message.reply('nice. <:problem:819305690106822706>')
```

However, the bot replies if a ping/channel's id contains 69. This obviously wasn't supposed to happen. How do I stop it?

Comment: But what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution to the problem. Instead of using a simple `in`, I ended up running the code through some regex that cut out anything encased in these: <>. The regex I ended up using was

```
re.sub(r'\<[^>]*\>', '', message.content)
```

which is a slight variation of the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex). Thus, the final code ended up being

```
if re.sub(r'\<[^>]*\>', '', message.content):
    await message.reply('nice. <:problem:819305690106822706>')
```