# How can I remove any text inside parentheses including the parentheses themselves in Python?

Tags: python, string

The program must remove all parentheses from the text and everything inside the parentheses.
When entering "text)" or "text (text)" everything works fine.
But there is an error in case I enter "text(".
I'm new to Python and I understand that my code is 100% bulky than it should be.
Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
print("Программа удаляет из текста все круглые скобки "
      "и всё, что было внутри этих скобок.")


# Создал функцию parentheses_text_remove.
# Она делает всю работу, а в конце мы просто вызываем её.
def parentheses_text_remove(text):
    # Цикл, чтобы находило все скобки в тексте.
    while "(" in text:
        # Переменная start, находит открывающую скобку.
        start = text.index("(")
        """
        Следующая строка кода нужна для удаления пробела перед "(".
        Слайсим весь текст до start, т.е. до "(" и ищем последний
        пробел до start.
        """
        start = text[:start].rfind(" ", 0, start)
        # Переменная end находит закрывающую скобку.
        end = text.index(")", start)
        """
        Объединяем всё, что ДО скобок с тем, что ПОСЛЕ.
        Всё, что внутри скобок, включая сами скобки,
        в новом тексте не участвует.
        """
        text = text[:start] + text[end + 1:]
    return text


# Добавил всё в цикл, чтобы имитировать какое-никакое общение.
while True:
    initial_input = input("Для запуска введите «Старт», "
                          "для выхода введите «Выход»."
                          "\n> ").lower().strip()
    if initial_input == "старт":
        while True:
            # Собственно, ввод и вывод текста.
            user_input = input("Введите текст: ")
            final_output = parentheses_text_remove(user_input)
            if user_input == "":
                print("Вы ничего не ввели. Попробуйте заново "
                      "или введите «Выход» для выхода.")
                continue
            elif user_input in ["выход", "Выход", "ВЫХОД"]:
                print("Выход из программы..."
                      "\n...завершён.")
                exit()
            print("Результат:", final_output)
    elif initial_input == "выход":
        print("Выход из программы..."
              "\n...завершён.")
        quit()
    else:
        print("Некорректный ввод. Попробуйте заново.")
        continue
```

Error when trying to enter "text(":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Python\myfile.py", line 38, in <module>
    final_output = parentheses_text_remove(user_input)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Python\myfile.py", line 19, in parentheses_text_remove
    end = text.index(")", start)
ValueError: substring not found
```

How to make the program ignore "text("?

I tried this:

```
if ")" not in text[start:]:
            text = text[:start] + "(" + text[start+1:]
            continue
```

But it doesn't work. In this case, If I enter "text(" the program does nothing. There is no error, I still can enter additional text but when I push Enter button nothing happens.

Comment: Why not just make an if statement to check if `)` exists in the string?

Comment: I tried. But since it didn't help, I'm not sure what to put into the statement

Comment: Can you use `re` --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex

Comment: You can't break out of the while loop with a `continue` statement.

Comment: @SimonUnderwood can you please check my statement for `)` above?

Comment: You should use `break` instead of `continue`.

Comment: @gre_gor why? For example, according to w3schools, I can use `continue`

Comment: @SimonUnderwood I tried it right now - the same error

Comment: I really doubt even w3schools would tell you to use `continue` to break out of the loop.

Comment: @gre_gor https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_continue.asp#:~:text=The%20continue%20keyword%20is%20used%20to%20end%20the%20current%20iteration%20in%20a%20for%20loop%20(or%20a%20while%20loop)%2C%20and%20continues%20to%20the%20next%20iteration.

Comment: It says continue, not break.

Answer (score 0):

```
def parentheses_text_remove(text):
    # keep removing pairs of '(' and ')' as long as there are any
    while '(' in text and ')' in text:
        for i, character in enumerate(text):
            # step through the characters until you encounter a closing bracket
            if character == ')':
                j = i
                # walk back until you encounter an opening bracket
                while text[j] != '(':
                    j -= 1
                # strip out the part in brackets
                text = text[:j] + text[i+1:]
                break
    return text

print(parentheses_text_remove(
    'Hello (remove this (remove this as well)) World (this needs to go (too))'
))
```

prints

```
Hello  World
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question *"Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?"* And OP has problem with text with not matching parentheses.

Comment: Well, there are comments explaining what the code does. Also, title states "How can I remove any text inside parentheses including the parentheses themselves in Python?", and I provided code that does exactly this.

Comment: You need to read more than the title.

Comment: The code also fails on `")("`.